# Angular reactive forms - File size validation

Tags: angular

I'm trying to validate the file size from a file input field with a custom validator but that validator doesn't have access to the file size. The value of the control within the validator only has the file name. Inside the component I can access the file size but I don't know how I can pass this to the validator.

**edit-form-config.ts**

```
    name: 'logo',
    label: 'Logo',
    helpText: 'Accepted file types: SVG, PNG, JPG and JPEG, up to 1mb.',
    type: 'form-file-upload',
    size: FormFieldSizeEnum.Full,
    validations: [
      {
        name: 'fileSize',
        validator: CustomValidators.fileSizeValidatorInKb(1000),
        message: 'File size is too large.',
      },
    ],
    required: true,
  },
```

**edit-form.component.html**

```
    <form-file-upload
      class="mb-20"
      [field]="_editFormConfig | getField: 'logo'"
      [parentForm]="form"
      (change)="onFileChange($event)"
    ></form-file-upload>
```

**edit-form.component.ts**

```
onFileChange(event: any): void {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
    const [file] = event.target.files;
    this.file = file;
    
    // Can access file size here
    this.file.size
  }
```

How can I pass this file size to the validator?

**custom-validator.ts**

```
  static fileSizeValidatorInKb(maxSize: number, file: File): ValidationErrors | null {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      if (control.value === null || control.value === undefined) {
        return null;
      }

      console.log(control); // Only get access to file name
      // TODO: get file size and convert to kb
    };
  }
```

I'm trying to get this validator to check the file size in kb and then either accept the file size or display the message that can be seen in **edit-form-config.ts**

Comment: You can set the validator on the fly by using the [`setValidators`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValidators) method on the AbstractControl in your component

Comment: Not sure if I can use the custom validator this way? @MichaelDoye